# How to prevent UUID from changing state when using copy-to-clipboard function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, qr-code

I managed to copy the generated UUID into my clipboard but whenever I click on the button, the UUID (and QR code) changes even though the page did not refresh. How to prevent the UUID from changing its state? Please refer to the codes below;

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import FileCopyIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FileCopy";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import QRCode from "react-qr-code";
import { CopyToClipboard } from "react-copy-to-clipboard";

export default function QRGenerator() {
  const adminId = uuid();

  const [qrcode, setQrcode] = useState({
    value: "",
    copied: false,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <CopyToClipboard
        text={adminId}
        onCopy={() => setQrcode({ copied: true })}
      >
        <Button>
          <FileCopyIcon />
        </Button>
      </CopyToClipboard>

      <Typography align="center" variant="caption" paragraph="true">
        Admin ID : {adminId}
        {qrcode.copied ? <span style={{ color: "red" }}>Copied.</span> : null}
      </Typography>
      <QRCode value={adminId} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet has two issues.

**First: adminId**

React hook will be called multiple time within its lifecycle, and it will be given different value based on `uuid()`

To solve it, you can use `useState` or `useRef` or move it to outside `QRGenerator` function.

**Second issue: updating state**

`setQrcode({ copied: true })}` mean you will replace the value `qrcode` value with `{ copied: true}` with value `undefined`

The below snippet will be the solution to the above issues

```
export default function QRGenerator() {
  const [adminId] = useState(uuid()); // or useRef(uuid());

  const [qrcode, setQrcode] = useState({
    value: "",
    copied: false,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <CopyToClipboard
        text={adminId}
        onCopy={() => setQrcode({...qrcode, copied: true })} // this change only `copied` value
      >
        <Button>
          <FileCopyIcon />
        </Button>
      </CopyToClipboard>

      <Typography align="center" variant="caption" paragraph="true">
        Admin ID : {adminId}
        {qrcode.copied ? <span style={{ color: "red" }}>Copied.</span> : null}
      </Typography>
      <QRCode value={adminId} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I didn't know that we can pass 1 argument in the useState hooks to make it constant.

Comment: you are welcome! :)... and pls try to figure out `useMemo` it might be a better way to use than `useState` in your case

Comment: I've tried using useMemo but I don't quite understand the meaning of dependencies in the array. It works though.  const adminId = useMemo(( ) =>  uuid( ),[ ]);

Comment: empty array `[]` means it will be called only once after component mounted.

Answer (score 2):

Every time the state is changed, render function is called. So the uuid is called again and it is changed.
If you need the uuid to be constant, we can use useState

```
  const [adminId] = useState(uuid());
```

Or We have to pass it as prop from the parent component so that for every rerender it wont change.

Comment: It works now. I always thought that if we use useState, we need to provide 2 arguments, the state and the setState and we only use it if we want to change the state of something.

Comment: useState gives us array of two values, first one is the value and the second variable is used to set the value. Here we are taking only the first one. you can check about destructive assignment es6 https://dev.to/sarah_chima/destructuring-assignment---arrays-16f